# Ref on component is null after force quitting and reopening app on Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this code for a react native app which uses [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps). I am trying to get the Callout component of the Marker to open immediately when the app launches, using the showCallout method of the Marker component by creating a ref on the Marker component. Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker, Callout } from "react-native-maps";
import { PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native";
import { apiKey } from "./apiKey";
import CustomCallout from "./CustomCallout";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
      locationGranted: null,
      currentWeather: "Loading weather data..."
    };
    this.requestLocationPermission = this.requestLocationPermission.bind(this);
    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);
    this.setMarkerRefresh = this.setMarkerRefresh.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.requestLocationPermission();
  }

  async getWeather(lat, long) {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
        `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${apiKey}/${lat},${long}`
      );
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      let thisHour = responseJson.hourly.data[0];
      this.setState(
        {
          currentWeather: `${thisHour.temperature} ${thisHour.windSpeed} ${
            thisHour.summary
          }`
        },
        this.setMarkerRefresh
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  setMarkerRefresh() {
    setTimeout(this.currentMarker.showCallout, 1);
  }

  async requestLocationPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: "Location Permission",
          message:
            "This app needs access to your location to provide you location data.",
          buttonPositive: "OK"
        }
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            this.setState({
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude,
              error: null,
              locationGranted: true
            });
            this.getWeather(
              position.coords.latitude,
              position.coords.longitude
            );
          },
          error => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
          { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 }
        );
      } else {
        this.setState({ locationGranted: false });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.locationGranted === false) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text> Please enable location to use this app. </Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else if (this.state.latitude === null || this.state.longitude === null) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text> {this.state.error} </Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
            style={styles.map}
            region={{
              latitude: this.state.latitude,
              longitude: this.state.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: 0.025,
              longitudeDelta: 0.025
            }}
          >
            <Marker
              coordinate={{
                latitude: this.state.latitude,
                longitude: this.state.longitude
              }}
              ref={ref => {
                this.currentMarker = ref;
              }}
            >
              <Callout tooltip={true}>
                <CustomCallout>
                  <Text style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {this.state.currentWeather}
                  </Text>
                </CustomCallout>
              </Callout>
            </Marker>
          </MapView>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
  },
  customView: {
    width: 140,
    height: 140
  }
});
```

The code works as intended on initial opening of the app. However, when I force quit the app and try to reopen it, I get this error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'currentMarker.showCallout')

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
setMarkerRefresh
```

I am not really sure what is going on in terms of component mounting/unmounting that causes this error. I have tried searching online but have not had much success. Could anyone help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your method, `setMarkerRefresh` to the

```
setMarkerRefresh() {
    // setTimeout(this.currentMarker.showCallout, 1);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.currentMarker.showCallout;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly thank you!! I have two questions with this though:  1. If I need the arrow function to bind this, why in my previous code did it work on the first load (but not the other times after force quitting)? and 2. Why don't I need to use an arrow function in the callback to setMarkerRefresh in getWeather?

Comment: I think your problem is related to the 'setTimeout' method. 'this' will not get, if you not bind the function 'setTimeout'. Now I bind the function so, we got the 'this'. If you get the answer, can you up-vote for my answer?